# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals during SNR calculation

Tags: matlab, fft, indices

i am trying to calculate SNR of non-sinusoidal signal,while calculating signal power, i am getting error. Kindly help, Thank you in advance

I tried to increase the length of FFT and leakage,i:e  N = 2^nextpow2(length(signal)); but no luck.
Sampling rate:16000

my code is as follows:

```
[signal, Fs] = audioread('40db_heart_insulation.wav');
N               = 8192; % FFT length
leak            = 150; %bins
fft_s           = fft(signal,N);
abs_fft_s       = abs(fft_s);
plot (abs_fft_s)
[~,p]           = max(abs_fft_s(1:N/2));
sigpos= [p-leak:p+leak N-p-leak:N-p+leak];% Finding the peak
sig_pow         = sum(abs_fft_s(sigpos));
```

Error:
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in heartsounds (line 17)
sig_pow         = sum(abs_fft_s(sigpos)); % signal power = sum of magnitudes of bins conrresponding to signal

Comment: So, when debugging your code, what is/are the value/s of/in `sigpos`? Any non-positive entries?

Comment: yes, but when i try remove them i:e sigpos>0 , but then SNR i get, is negative, which shouldn't be. @HansHirse

Comment: But that's a different point! You asked for help to solve the mentioned error. The solution is not to use non-positive indices when accessing an array. On the other issue: Maybe shifting your non-positive entries can help? But since your question then is more related to general signal processing, I guess moving your question to https://dsp.stackexchange.com would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a negative value of `sigpos`, e.g. `N`<`p+leak`. Try adding this line:

`sigpos = sigpos(sigpos > 0)`

Comment: yes, but when i try remove them i:e sigpos>0 , but then SNR i get is negative, which shouldn't be.

Comment: But my solution fixes the error in your original post, right?. I can't say anything about SNR since it's an unrelated calculation that you haven't described at all.